# Mockito how to test save method with DTO

Tags: spring-boot, validation, service, mockito, spring-test

I dont know how can i test save method with mockito. The problem is that the test is incorrect because I am creating a new object in the service and I have no idea how to fix it

Service

```
@Validated
public class ProductService {

   private final CategoryService categoryService;

    public ProductService(CategoryService categoryService){
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
    }

    public void addProduct(Long categoryId,@Valid AddProductDto addProductDto) throws DataAccessException{

        CategoryModel categoryModel = categoryService.getCategoryById(categoryId);

        ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
        productModel.setProducent(addProductDto.getProducent());
        productModel.setPrice(addProductDto.getPrice());
        productModel.setName(addProductDto.getName());
        productModel.setSlider(addProductDto.getSlider());
        productModel.setImage(addProductDto.getImage());
        productModel.setDescription(addProductDto.getDescription());
        productModel.setQuantityAvailable(addProductDto.getQuantityAvailable());
        productModel.setCategoryModel(categoryModel);

        productRepository.save(productModel);

    }
}
```

DTO:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class AddProductDto implements Serializable {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Wprowadź poprawną nazwę nazwe")
    @Length(min = 3, max = 220, message = "Wprowadź poprawną długość nazwy przedmiotu")
    private final String name;
    @NotNull(message = "Uzupełnij Slider")
    private final Boolean slider;
    @NotNull(message = "Wprowadź poprawną ilość")
    @Min(message = "Wprowadź poprawną ilość", value = 0)
    private Integer quantityAvailable;
    @Length(min = 1, max = 220, message = "Wprowadź poprawną długość nazwy producenta")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Wprowadź poprawnego producenta")
    private final String producent;
    @Length(min = 5, max = 220, message = "Wprowadź poprawny opis przedmiotu")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Wprowadź poprawny opis")
    private final String description;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Wprowadź poprawne zdjęcie")
    @Length(min = 1, max = 240, message = "Wprowadź poprawne zdjęcie przedmiotu")
    private final String image;
    @Min(message = "Wprowadź poprawną cenę", value = 1)
    @NotNull(message = "Wprowadź cenę")
    private final Double price;
}
```

My test:

```
@Test
void testAddProductSuccess(){

//given
AddProductDto addProductDto = AddProductDto.builder()
        .producent("Logitech")
        .price(1.0)
        .name("Logitech G-403")
        .slider(false)
        .image("myszka1.jpg")
        .description("Dzięki przemyślanej budowie waży jedynie 59 g, dzięki czemu Twoja dłoń nie męczy się podczas użytkowania.")
        .quantityAvailable(100)
        .build();

ProductModel productModel = ProductModel.builder()
        .producent("Logitech")
        .price(1.0)
        .name("Logitech G-403")
        .slider(false)
        .image("myszka1.jpg")
        .description("Dzięki przemyślanej budowie waży jedynie 59 g, dzięki czemu Twoja dłoń nie męczy się podczas użytkowania.")
        .quantityAvailable(100)
        .build();


Set<ConstraintViolation<AddProductDto>> violations = validator.validate(addProductDto);

//when
productService.addProduct(1L,addProductDto);

//verify
verify(productRepository,times(1)).save(productModel);
assertTrue(violations.isEmpty());
}
```

Test Result

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
productRepository.save(
   model.ProductModel@55a88417
);

Actual invocations have different arguments:
productRepository.save(
   ProductModel@18acfe88
);
```

The test is incorrect because in the service I create a new ProductModel object and it is not the same object that I am checking. And I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Why doesn't your `ProductModel` override equals & hashCode? Also, it seems you are using two different classes/types "model.ProductModel" vs "ProductModel"

Answer (score 0):

Best way to test `JpaRepository` is using the `@DataJpaTest` annotation on you test class. Inject repository under test and that's it. You should forget the hell of creating when and then statements. You can find the reference guide [here](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-data-jpa-test/)